# Can you recommend me any books about infinitesimal probability?

Tags: probability, infinitesimals

Can you recommend me any books about infinitesimal probability?

There are several good books about infinitesimal calculus but it is hard to find any books about infinitesimal probability...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is Herzberg:

Herzberg, Frederik S. Stochastic calculus with infinitesimals. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 2067. Springer, Heidelberg, 2013.

See [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-33149-7).

Answer (score 0):

Edward Nelson wrote a book on probability from the internal set theory approach to nonstandard analysis:

Nelson, Edward. Radically Elementary Probability Theory.

ISBN-13 is 978-0691084749.